# Enforce axis limits in JZY3D plot

Tags: java, jzy3d

Could anyone help me figure out how to set axis limits for a Jzy3D plot? I have a plot where I have rendered a mesh and a few lines. I've tried to limit the axis by changing the bounding box on the axis and all. This manages to limit the actual axis grid that's rendered to the limits I'm setting, but the rest of the surfaces of the mesh and the other lines in the plot still continue to be rendered... Anyone know how to cut out the things that are outside of the axes limits?

[image: Sample image of rendering issue]